# Grails, domain class default value for Field

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I want to update date Field when any row updated. Means whenever I update perticular field the date need to be changed automatically.

How can I got this in grails Domain class??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails can do that for you!

Go to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html and search for 'Automatic timestamping'

There are 2 fields supported:
*"By defining a `lastUpdated` and `dateCreated` property these will be automatically updated for you by GORM."*

Comment: @sbglasius, what that mean of remember to answer??

Comment: I just mean, if you like the answer given by @David, you should accept it, that way he gets credit for it.